# import .ics TRIGGERS in outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm trying to import my hosted calendar into outlook with triggers.  The calendar imports correctly, however, the triggers are not imported.

A comment on this question [Outlook Calendar - import with reminders/alarms?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/outlook-calendar-import-with-remindersalarms/7d5f9690-7309-4a4d-8b4c-788c093b5b36), back in 2010, says that there is no option for importing with reminders.

Am I missing something in my VEVENT?

Or

Outlook is really not supporting importing VALARM ?

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:My Summary
DTSTAMP:20170413T192158Z
UID:1000SomeUniqueIdentifier0001
DTSTART:20170411T113000Z
DTEND:20170411T193000Z
LOCATION:SomeLocation
DESCRIPTION:TheDescription
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT60M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

Bonus:
This is how Outlook Exports VALARM

```
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would answer this.

Currently, as of Apr 2017, you cannot import VALARM via a hosted .ics file into your outlook calendar.

Comment: But why the **** not?  :)  Very frustrating.
This works for me in 2022, at least in Outlook for macOS:

BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM

Comment: Wow! They did it! Finally! Here is a document about how it behaves.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_standards/ms-stanoical/908dc008-2a3a-48c1-88d0-633cdc0aaeee